# node 16.11.1 and npm 8.0.0 npm ERR! code ECONNRESET corp proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I'm getting this issue to to proxy

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/camel-case: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

my **.npmrc** looks like this:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
https-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
user-agent=npm/8.0.0 node/v16.11.0 darwin x64
```

I have using cntml for proxy settings

please any idea what is wrong in settings here?